# How to select rows from a matrix in. R

Tags: r

Newbie here, so maybe this problem has an obvious solution:

I have a large matrix with no row or column names. I would like to create a data frame consisting of rows from the matrix where a column has a particular value. The column doesn't have a name and I don't know its position in advance.

Here is a small example:

```
  S <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,0,0,-2,0,1,2),5,2)
```

which prints as:

```
        [,1] [,2]
  [1,]    1    0
  [2,]    1   -2
  [3,]    2    0
  [4,]    3    1
  [5,]    0    2
```

now I want to create a data frame of rows that contain an even entry in some column. This should produce a df with rows 1,2,3,5. In my situation there are 1000 columns so I can't enumerate all the columns. (What I need is a quantifier that ranges across columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do like this

```
subset(
  as.data.frame(S),
  (V1 * V2) %% 2 == 0
)
```

which gives

```
  V1 V2
1  1  0
2  1 -2
3  2  0
5  0  2
```

---

If you have many columns, you can use an alternative

```
subset(
  u <- as.data.frame(S),
  Reduce("*", u) %% 2 == 0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Update:
Thanks to valuable comment of MrFlick:

`S %>% rowwise() %>% filter(any(is.even(c_across())))`

First answer:

1. matrix to dataframe
2. `across` with created function `is.even`
3. `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
is.even <- function(v) v %% 2 == 0

S <- data.frame(S)
S %>% mutate(across(everything(), is.even,  .names = "{.col}.{.fn}")) %>%
    filter(X1.1 != FALSE  | X2.1 != FALSE) %>% 
    select(X1, X2)
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2
1  1  0
2  1 -2
3  2  0
4  0  2
```

Comment: I like this idea but the `mutate()` step seems a bit of a detour. How about something more like: `S %>% rowwise() %>% filter(any(is.even(c_across())))`

Comment: Thank you MrFlick. This is a great point!

Comment: The "update" does not work for me `Error in UseMethod("rowwise") : 
  no applicable method for 'rowwise' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"` Perhaps this is meant to follow the `S` conversion to dataframe?

Comment: You have to transform `S` to a data frame. This code works: `library(dplyr)
is.even <- function(v) v %% 2 == 0

S %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% filter(any(is.even(c_across())))`

Answer (score 2):

You can test for "evenness" by look at the value mod 2 (`%% 2`) and checking if it's zero. You can perform this action across all rows using `rowSums()` to check for any TRUE values. So you can do

```
S[rowSums(S %% 2 ==0)>0, ]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    1   -2
# [3,]    2    0
# [4,]    0    2
```

to get just the rows with an even value.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` from `base R` on a logical matrix constructed with `%%` to create a logical vector that can be used to subset the rows

```
S[ apply(!(S %% 2), 1, any),]
```

-ouput

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1   -2
[3,]    2    0
[4,]    0    2
```

---

Or with `collapse` for efficiency

```
library(collapse)
sbt(S, dapply(S, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) any(! x %% 2)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1   -2
[3,]    2    0
[4,]    0    2
```

---

Or use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(S) %>% 
      filter(if_any(everything(), ~ !(. %% 2) ))
   V1 V2
1  1  0
2  1 -2
3  2  0
4  0  2
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful solutions. I have one more step that i would like to add: graphing all the selected rows on a single graph. any ideas, here?